# cmd + shift + o opens dropdown, cannot find application files

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I tried to use the shortcut `cmd` + `shift` + `o` to open an application file on Mac, but none of my file names resolve when I enter them into the input.  The only files appear to be system/python library files.

This feature used to work for me and it appears to have stopped working overnight.

EDIT: I have restarted PyCharm and my mac multiple times.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your mac?

Comment: @Mike yes i have multiple times :/

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your project?

Comment: @mike can you send me a link of what exactly you mean please?

Comment: On the main menu choose Build | Rebuild Project. Edit: Oh wait you're in pycharm

Comment: My bad I don't think you can rebuild in pycharm. Have you tried invalidating your caches?

Comment: @Mike No i havent yet, Im afraid of what I might lose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198622/discussion-between-mike-and-redress).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution to the problem. He had to invalidate his caches and restart.